# can I use both React and plain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to build a website using React and [Stacks Design](https://stackoverflow.design/). For example, to open and hide Dropdown Menu or Tooltip we can put proper `data`  attributes on the button and then `Stacks.js` do the rest. I know that in React we can use `hooks` for this so the question is whether using pain javascript to do it doesnt contradict with the idea behind react? It works but I'm pretty new in React and I would like to know whether I dont do something what is prohibited in React

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using react you are actually using Javascript on the client side. React gives you some help when developing things for example the dropdown menu. You could make use of the useState hook to manage the state of the dropdown (wheter is opened or closed). Not using these hooks when you could use them is just a waste of time and performance. Of course you can write plain javascript scripts, but try to use hooks :)

- [useState Hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState)

Check this reddit comment also:

[Comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/atgke2/react_vs_vanilla_js_when_to_use_each_of_them/eh0z97a/)
 by      [u/MetaSemaphore](https://www.reddit.com/user/MetaSemaphore) from discussion      [React vs Vanilla JS, when to use each of them?](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/atgke2/react_vs_vanilla_js_when_to_use_each_of_them/)
 in      [webdev](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/)